# Gamma Fit for R0 in SIR Model Sometimes Shows a Spike in the Graph

Tags: python, bioinformatics, data-fitting, gamma-distribution

we're doing the SIR model. Sometimes when we run the simulation a hundred times we get a weird gamma distribution for the R0s that looks like this.We ran this for 10 simulations and the R0 values were:

```
    [5.69740264 5.02800221 5.31973113 7.6658689  6.82869682 5.67290781
     6.64877547 8.41010163 5.96815674 5.75569205]
    And shape, loc, scale = 0.2643804075295388 5.028002206297035 1.5562608322420877
```

[image]

Most of the time it looks as expected like this. We ran this for 10 simulations and the R0 values were:

```
     [7.78631152 6.51781625 5.94022457 6.33005114 6.37227342 6.41832669
     5.75049799 6.86638545 6.42763756 6.83041837]
     And shape, loc, scale = 4.054455853718435 5.442115990997264 0.2668371712255179
```

[image]

Do you have any idea why this might happen? I think it has to do with the shape of the gamma fit, but why is it so different when the R0 values look really similar?